# Going .pluck crazy. What is a realistic limit on query with array

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-postgresql

I've used `.pluck(:id)` quite often (and `map` before it) to get a set of record ids. This is usually to get a set of related model records (e.g,, :people has_many :scores, as :assessed)

Lets say I have 10,000 people, but a query on People limits it to say 1,000.

```
people_ids = people.pluck(:id) #people a relation/scoped
scores = Score.where(:assessed_type => 'People', :assessed_id => people_ids)
```

There would be more to the Score query, but my basic question is querying with an array of say 1000 ids a bad idea?

I should point out that the filtered Score query would be used to get a new set of People. This is a filter on People.

I only have a few hundred records in my test DB, and that works fine - but there must be a point where psql or Rails is going to blow up. In production, I don't see going more that 1000 ids since People is automatically filter before this Score option is used.

Comment: Couldn't you avoid the problem altogether by leaving the logic in the database and using a JOIN or subquery instead?

Comment: I didn't realize that subqueries were added to rails 3. I guess I used .pluck(:id) to simulate a subquery. Since this is a polymorphic relation, it took a little while to wrap my head around it, but ended up just a simple select clause.

`scores = Score.where(:assessed_type => 'People', :assessed_id => people.select(:id)).where(...rest of score query)`

Slightly less cost.  Thanks!